Does DLT-Daemon support for FreeRTOS
I want dlt-daemon for freertos, I'm trying with MSVC demo examples and tried creating a task that executes the dlt-daemon, I also tried different method but facing alot of errors
I want to know whether the dlt-daemon support for freeRTOS if yes, i wanted a detailed step to configure or create project with dlt-daemon for freeRTOS
